# How can you set your path = Path to automatically be a users Downloads folder?

Tags: python, directory, path, pysimplegui

I am wanting to set up a system of CSV formatters in conjunction with a PySimpleGUI program. I want the output file to go to the users Downloads folder, but currently I know how to only use the Path method for my own Downloads folder. If I packaged this up, it would not be dynamic.

```
path = Path(r"C:\\Users\\xxx.xxxxx\\downloads\\Finished_File.csv")
```

I am unsure of other ways to go about auto-filling the user info without inputting it manually

My only other thinking is perhaps have this change dynamically with PySimpleGui using a list of potential names, and then having the user set who they are?

Comment: Side note: you probably shouldn't be using a raw string literal (prefixed with `r`) and double backslashes together.

Comment: THANK YOU! I'm building this to stream lie work-flows in my healthcare job. It gives me an excuse to learn to program while I work -- I'm quite a beginner, so I appreciate your input!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Find it manually before saving uisng [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

```
from pathlib import Path
users_download_path = str(Path.home() / "Downloads")
res =str( users_download_path) + '\' + str('Finished_File.csv')
path = Path(res)
```

Comment: This isn't seeming to work. Could a permission on my work computer be blocking it? No errors occur, it jus is not exporting when I push df.to_csv(path, header=True, index=False)

Comment: @BHhargav it seems to print C:\Users\kye.hache\DownloadsFinished_File.csv

How do i get the extra \ in there? it isnt wanting to work, it sees the back \ as an operator to the string.

Comment: Why are you creating strings from a path, then back to a path? It's probably better to just stay in the `pathlib` world, e.g. `Path.home() / "Downloads" / "Finished_file.csv"`. No `str()` needed.

Comment: this is the changes I made prior to this comment -- you both did it a little cleaner than me, though :)

Thank you both.

Comment: `'\'` doesn't do what you think it does. Are you looking for `'\\'`?

Comment: On Windows and some Linux distros the name of the download directory is localized so will not be "Downloads". In addition on Windows the user is free to rename or move the Downloads directory/path.